# AWS S3 vs Elemental MediaStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-mediastore, aws-mediaservices

This is more of a philosophical question:

For a simple video application, which AWS services is the the best to choose, S3 or Elemental MediaStore?

and

And at which point will one be better to an other.

The question is mostly in regards to performance, as I am aware different possibilities in the sdk's.

**Background**
I am making a video website for my company, which will be used for simple instructional videos (screen recordings of how to do stuff in different applications). The videos er mp4 videos made vide iMovie and are around 30s to 1min.

In my website, I see no performance differences for the videos. Would I see a difference if the videos was 4k 1 hour long?

I like using MediaStore simply because it seems more appropriate for videos, but is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MediaStore has a cacheing layer and lower latency than s3 so it is optimized for live streaming and just in time packaging of live and vod.

Comment: can mediastore be used for already package HLS, DASH content? If yes, then can we map mediastore to CDN service like Akamai?

Answer (score 8):

Use MediaStore for live video.

Use S3 for video on demand

Answer (score 6):

**You can take a look at this diagram:**

[image: aws s3 vs elemental mediastore]